# How to use setDelay for animation within an AnimatorSet?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a set of animations, but the start delay value does not seem to be respected. Example:

```
ObjectAnimator a1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view1, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f);
a1.setDuration(500);
a1.setStartDelay(500);

ObjectAnimator a2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view2, "translationX", ...);
a2.setDuration(500);

AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(a1, a2);
set.start();
```

I can see the alpha animation starts immediately. If I don't try to play them together, the delay is respected and works fine. Can the delay not be used if part of an AnimatorSet?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play the animations in sequence, don't use `ObjectAnimator.setStartDelay()`. It's not designed for that use case.

Use `AnimatorSet.playSequentially()` instead:

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playSequentially(a2, a1);
set.start();
```